# Создание компонента, наследника TBevel, с дополнительным свойством - Заглавие (String)

Tags: delphi, компоненты, класс

Полное задание такое:

> наследник TBevel с свойством - заглавие (TString) с возможность менять индексацию (верхний и нижний индекс).

Есть подходящий компонент - RichEdit, но вся проблема в том, что я не могу создать этот компонент в своём классе. Сам Bevel создаётся на ура, а вот с RichEdit - проблемы. Вот код, но в нём толком ничего нет.

```
    unit MyBevel;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.ComCtrls,
  //Vcl.StdCtrls,
  MyBevelTools;

type
  TMyBevel = class;
  TMyBevelChange = procedure (Sender: TMyBevel; Title: String) of object;
  {TMyBevelTitle = class(TRichEdit)
  private
    CTitle: TRichEdit;
    procedure Create(Sender: TObject);

  end;  }

  TMyBevel = class(TBevel)
  public
  constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    CTitle: TRichEdit;
    fTitle: String;
  published
    property Title: String read fTitle write fTitle;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;

end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('My Components', [TMyBevel]);
end;

{ TMyBevel }

constructor TMyBevel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  **В этом моменте проблемы**
end;

destructor TMyBevel.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyBevel.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  {CTitle:= TRichEdit.Create(self);
  CTitle.SetParentComponent(self);
  with CTitle do begin
  Top := 10;
  Left:= 10;
  Width:= 100;
  Height:= 20;
  Text:= 'No title';
  end;}

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во- первых, внутренние компоненты нужно создавать в `Create`, а не на каждой перерисовке.

Однако, это в данном случае не нужно, поскольку `TBevel` - **не оконный компонент**, а наследник `TGraphicControl`, и не может быть родительским окном для других контролов.

Судя по указанию `TBevel`, вам нужно создать нечто вроде расширенного `TLabel` с некоторыми возможностями форматирования. При этом не указано - как именно должна передаваться информация об верхнем и нижнем индексе. Возможно, вам нужно самому определить это - например, через последовательности вроде `'\u', '\d'` или `<sup>superscript</sup>`, как здесь на SO. В таком случае нужно будет интерпретировать `Caption` перед отрисовкой и соответственно сдвигать символы или использовать другие средства.

По-большому счёту, внутри компонента может существовать невидимый TRichEdit, который будет отрисовывать себя в указанный Canvas, но мне кажется, что для такой задачи это перебор.

Посмотрите также разделы Enhanced Labels и formatted labels на torry, может быть, оттуда что-то почерпнёте.

Comment: Я говорил, что код - пустышка. Можете пожалуйста привести пример такого Create, у меня не получается создать RichEdit внутри Bevel. И, если такое возможно, хотелось бы RichEdit за пределами Bevel сделать (вверху по центру допустим). И еще, что за последовательности вроде '\u', '\d'?

Comment: `не получается создать RichEdit внутри Bevel` - я же написал, что это невозможно.

Comment: что за последовательности вроде '\u', '\d'?

Comment: Ну up  и down для переключения в нужный режим

Comment: А можно пример кода? И еще, как я создам Label, если в Bevel ничего размещать нельзя?

Comment: Label не нужно создавать, это я так упомянул, что ваш Bevel будет фактически как Label. Кода у меня нет.